# Getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when using Spring kafka to produce a message

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm trying to deploy a spring boot app on Pivotal Cloud Foundry to use spring kafka to send a message to kafka and getting below error with 1GB memory in manifest.yml. My sprint boot app has just one Rest Controller with only one endpoint to send a message. The app is starting without any issue if I change the memory to 2GB in my manifest.yml and it's taking almost 1.3 GB - 1.8 GB to run the app. I'm wondering why this simple app is taking so much memory. Is it because of Kafka ?
In our app, we are using org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient

We are using Spring 2.x, java 8 and buildpack 3.9 with this app.

[APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT # java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
{APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT # -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="/home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/killjava.sh"

Any help to understand this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I figured out the issue, it's the 'org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient' class causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used VisualVM and figured out that 'org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient' is consuming more memory.